# Get retention policy using Rest API in Exchange Online

Tags: rest, exchange-server, office365api

I need to create a rest call which will return the title, body and retention policy(very important) of each mail of the current user mailbox using REST Api. I tried this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#GetMessages , but retention policy doesn't seem to be a value returned by this api. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried yet? Which documentation did you read?

Comment: I tried this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#GetMessages , but retentiy policy doesn't seem to be in the values returned...So i wanted to know if there was another way to get the info.